# write a program to automatically generate tweets

Tags: perl, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to create a twitter account and then write a perl program which can automatically generate and send tweets through that account. I've been trying to research how to do this through twitter's documentation, but everything I can find involves tweeting from a website or an app, which isn't really what I'd like to do.

I apologize for asking such a basic question, but I need help just to get started - 1) is it possible to do what I am asking (to write a program which generates and sends tweets, without the mediation of a website or app)? 2) Do I need Oauth for this, or is the authentication process different?

Any information about how to proceed is very much appreciated.

Comment: A website and app are just are programs so yes its possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [Net::Twitter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Twitter) module. The documentation for that will answer all your questions.